# Recursive Tree formatted to specific HTML

Tags: php, html, hierarchy, recursive-datastructures

Can someone please help me with the proper logic to format a hierarchical array into the following HTML pattern?  I realize this is semi-redundant with many posts, but I can't seem to get my drill in and drill out of the recursive process to format the way I need it to.

This PHP style array was created using a recursive function which was fed from a database. The recursive function is working fine as far as creating the array.  Here is a sample array structure with a corresponding picture of what it should look like once formatted in the HTML. Note that the 'c' child node is an array of one to many children with potentially any number of additional 'c' nodes.  Each leaf node correctly terminates a given chain, so in this case, 'DELIVERY POINT' and 'PORT' are leaf nodes with direct parents as you can see in the diagram.

Example Hardcoded Formatted Hierarchical Result:
[image]

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'PKEY_MODULE' => '4',
    'PKEY_ENTITY' => '15',
    'ENTITY' => 'LEGAL ENTITY',
    'PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT' => '0',
    'c' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'PKEY_MODULE' => '6',
        'PKEY_ENTITY' => '29',
        'ENTITY' => 'PHYSICAL SITE',
        'PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT' => '15',
        'c' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'PKEY_MODULE' => '6',
            'PKEY_ENTITY' => '30',
            'ENTITY' => 'ADDRESS',
            'PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT' => '29',
            'c' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'PKEY_MODULE' => '6',
                'PKEY_ENTITY' => '31',
                'ENTITY' => 'DELIVERY POINT',
                'PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT' => '30',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'PKEY_MODULE' => '6',
            'PKEY_ENTITY' => '32',
            'ENTITY' => 'STRUCTURE',
            'PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT' => '29',
            'c' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'PKEY_MODULE' => '6',
                'PKEY_ENTITY' => '33',
                'ENTITY' => 'AREA',
                'PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT' => '32',
                'c' => 
                array (
                  0 => 
                  array (
                    'PKEY_MODULE' => '6',
                    'PKEY_ENTITY' => '34',
                    'ENTITY' => 'LOCATION',
                    'PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT' => '33',
                    'c' => 
                    array (
                      0 => 
                      array (
                        'PKEY_MODULE' => '6',
                        'PKEY_ENTITY' => '35',
                        'ENTITY' => 'PORT',
                        'PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT' => '34',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Here is what the HTML should end up looking like - I hardcoded this example for comparison as displayed in the linked image.

```
    <div class="hv-item">
       <div class="hv-item-parent"><p class="node">LEGAL ENTITY</p></div>
       <div class="hv-item-children">
           <div class="hv-item-child">
             <div class="hv-item">
                <div class="hv-item-parent"><p class="node">PHYSICAL SITE</p></div>
                <div class="hv-item-children">
                   <div class="hv-item-child">
                      <div class="hv-item">
                         <div class="hv-item-parent"><p class="node">ADDRESS</p></div>
                         <div class="hv-item-children">
                            <div class="hv-item-child">
                               <p class="node">DELIVERY POINT</p>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="hv-item-child">
                      <div class="hv-item">
                         <div class="hv-item-parent"><p class="node">STRUCTURE</p></div>
                         <div class="hv-item-children">
                             <div class="hv-item-child">
                               <div class="hv-item">
                                  <div class="hv-item-parent"><p class="node">AREA</p></div>
                                  <div class="hv-item-children">
                                     <div class="hv-item-child">
                                        <div class="hv-item">
                                           <div class="hv-item-parent"><p class="node">LOCATION</p></div>
                                           <div class="hv-item-children">
                                              <div class="hv-item-child"><p class="node">PORT</p></div>
                                           </div>
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

And for reference, here is the recursive function I'm using to format the array - I took it from stack.

```
function get_entity_hierarchy($array, $parent) {
   $branch = array();
   foreach ($array as $a) {
      if ($a["PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT"] == $parent) {        
         $child = get_entity_hierarchy($array, $a["PKEY_ENTITY"]);
         if ($child) {
            $a['c'] = $child;
         }
         $branch[] = $a;         
      }
   }
   return $branch;
}
```

And last but not least, here is the dataset I'm starting with - returned as an associative array from the database:

Data Rows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's still a couple trailing div nodes that I haven't gotten fixed and for modules that have multiple parent nodes (parallel trees essentially) the formatting needs some work, but this gets me close enough for horseshoes for now.  The $str and $recursive_count variables are static and declared prior to the function call.

```
function format_tree($array) {
   $str = '';
   static $recursive_count = 0;
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
         if ($key > 0 && $value["PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT"] != 0) { $str .= '<div class="hv-item-child">'; }
         if ($key > 0 && $value["PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT"] == 0) { $str .= '<br><br>'; }
         if (array_key_exists('c', $value)) {
            $str .= '<div class="hv-item">';
            $str .= '<div class="hv-item-parent"><p class="node">'.html_request_link('M','R03', $value["PKEY_ENTITY"], $value["ENTITY"]).'</p></div>';
            $str .= '<div class="hv-item-children">';
            $str .= '<div class="hv-item-child">';
            $recursive_count++;
            $str .= format_tree($value['c']);
            $recursive_count--;
            if ($key > 0 && $value["PKEY_ENTITY_PARENT"] != 0) {$str .= '</div>';}
            if ($recursive_count > 0) $str .= '</div></div></div>';
         } else {
            $str .= '<p class="node">'.html_request_link('M','R03', $value["PKEY_ENTITY"], $value["ENTITY"]).'</p></div>';
         }
      }
   }
   return $str;
}
```